# Google App Engine + AdWords API: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/soap/SOAPException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-ads-api

I know a lot so far about this exception. But I am wondering, if any of you tried to use AdWords API on GAE. AdWords uses Axis as underlying WS library, which do not work on GAE and unfortunately I cannot find solution to make it working. I tried already this: http://dev.bizo.com/2009/04/calling-soap-web-services-on-google-app.html

Does any of you know if there is a way to use AdWords API on GAE with Java?

Thanks in advance for any help
Konrad

Comment: How do you know the library in question doesn't work on App Engine? Have you tried including it? Why did the linked solution not work for you? It's hard to suggest an answer when you say you've tried stuff but don't say why it didn't work.

Comment: I did try to include it. I even tried to use it. What you get is exception in the subject line. This is due to GAE jax-ws lack of support. So that's why I am asking if anyone had any luck with using AdWords API on GAE. The only solution I found so far is under provided link, but unfortunately does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the adwords client library uses some things that forbiden in GAE's sandboxed environment.

This was resolved by a patch: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-java/issues/detail?id=62

For more info look here: http://penumbro.us/post/1135755221/adwords-api-on-app-engine-java-part-3